# Extracting probabilities from all classes in Tensorflow from CNN

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, probability, conv-neural-network

I have a trained CNN which is producing the correct predictions for determining the anticipated class, however I want to see the probabilities for each of the classes as a list. I tried to add a softmax function, but I am getting a error about having negative dimensions.  I have read multiple versions of this question, and have seen what appear to be multiple solutions, however, it seems that one size does not fit all, and while I have tried various solutions with eval and run statements; none of them appear to work in this model. The code I'm using is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import csv
SpeciesID = {'None':0}

def extract_data(filename, CSV_Origin_File):
    print("extracting data...")

    NUM_LABELS = 113 
    NUM_FEATURES = 10816


    labels = []
    fvecs = []
    rowCount = 0


    for IDline in open(CSV_Origin_File):
        IDrow = IDline.split(',')
        INkey = IDrow[6]
        INvalue = IDrow[9]
        SpeciesID.update({INkey:INvalue})

    #iterate over the rows, split the label from the features
    #convert the labels to integers and features to floats

    for line in open(filename):
        rowCount = rowCount + 1
        row = line.split(',')
        labels.append(row[0])#(int(row[7]))

        for x in row [0:10816]: #was 3-10820
            #print("fvecs>>>", x)
            fvecs.append(float(x))

    #convert the array of float arrasy into a numpy float matrix
    fvecs_np = np.matrix(fvecs).astype(np.float32)

    #convert the array of int lables inta a numpy array
    labels_np = np.array(labels).astype(dtype=np.uint8)

    #convert the int numpy array into a one-hot matrix
    labels_onehot = (np.arange(NUM_LABELS) == labels_np[:, None]).astype(np.float32)
    print("arrays converted")
    return fvecs_np, labels_onehot

# Create some wrappers for simplicity
def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1): #Layer 1 : Convolutional layer
    # Conv2D wrapper, with bias and relu activation
    #print("conv2d")
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME') # Strides are the tensors...list of integers.  Tensors=data
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)  #bias is the tuning knob
    return tf.nn.relu(x) #rectified linear unit (activation function)


def maxpool2d(x, k=2): #Layer 2 : Takes samples from the image. (This is a 4D tensor)
    #print("maxpool2d")
    # MaxPool2D wrapper
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],
                          padding='SAME')


def conv_net(x, wc1, wc2, wd1, Wout, bc1, bc2, bd1, Bout, dropout):
    #print("conv_net setup")
    # Reshape input picture
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 104, 104, 1])  #-->52x52 , -->26x26x64

    # Convolution Layer
    conv1 = conv2d(x, wc1, bc1) #defined above already
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)
    #print(conv1.get_shape)

    # Convolution Layer
    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, wc2, bc2)  #wc2 and bc2 are just placeholders...could actually skip this layer...maybe
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)
    #print(conv2.get_shape)

    # Fully connected layer
    # Reshape conv2 output to fit fully connected layer input
    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, wd1.get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, wd1), bd1)
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1) #activation function for the NN
    # Apply Dropout
    #fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout) #NO DROPOUT FOR TESTING!!!

    # Output, class prediction

    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, Wout), Bout)
    #print(out, "OUTPUT_________$$$")
    return out


def TestModels(InputFile, RefFile):
        fvecs_np, labels_onehot = extract_data(InputFile, RefFile)

        print('RESTORING NN MODEL')

        weights = {}
        biases = {}
        sess=tf.Session()  
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

        #Load meta graph and restore weights

        ModelID = "CNN_PICORNA_UCONN2-1000.meta" 
        print("RESTORING:::", ModelID)

        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(ModelID)

        saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))

        graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")
        y = graph.get_tensor_by_name("y:0")
        keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) 
        y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 113])

        wc1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("wc1:0")
        wc2 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("wc2:0")
        wd1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("wd1:0")
        Wout = graph.get_tensor_by_name("Wout:0")

        bc1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("bc1:0")
        bc2 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("bc2:0")
        bd1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("bd1:0")
        Bout = graph.get_tensor_by_name("Bout:0")

        weights = {wc1, wc2, wd1, Wout}
        biases = {bc1, bc2, bd1, Bout}

        pred = conv_net(x, wc1, wc2, wd1, Wout, bc1, bc2, bd1, Bout, keep_prob)

        prediction=tf.argmax(pred,1)
        best = sess.run([prediction],feed_dict={x: fvecs_np})

        probstesting = tf.nn.softmax(y,1)

        print("NEXTArgmax") 

        predY = prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: fvecs_np}, session=sess)

        PredSTR = str(predY[0])

        ProbBest = sess.run([probstesting], feed_dict={x: fvecs_np})

        print("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%")
        print("Predicted::: ", predY,  (list(SpeciesID.keys())[list(SpeciesID.values()).index(PredSTR)]))
        print("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%")

TestModels("/users/rwbarrettemac/desktop/NN_DB/VirPlotOUT_TESTX.csv", "/users/rwbarrettemac/Picorna_NN/PicornaALL_INv2.csv")
```

While I get the correct prediction for the expected class when running a test sample through, I am getting the following error from my attempt to get the probabilities, which is being thrown from the line:

```
ProbBest = sess.run([probstesting], feed_dict={x: fvecs_np})
```

The error statement it kicks back is:

```
2017-10-23 17:53:36.855270: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1148]    Invalid argument: Shape [-1,113] has negative dimensions
2017-10-23 17:53:36.855314: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:644]  Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Shape [-1,113] has negative  dimensions
      [[Node: y = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,113],  _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
2017-10-23 17:53:36.855424: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1148]   Invalid argument: Shape [-1,113] has negative dimensions
2017-10-23 17:53:36.855441: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:644]  Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Shape [-1,113] has negative  dimensions
     [[Node: y = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,113],   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
Traceback (most recent call last):

...lots more of the same....

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Shape [-1,113] has negative dimensions
     [[Node: y = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,113],   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

(tensorflow) aapnypi2vtrbarr:~ rwbarrettemac$
```

I've also tried the following with no luck:

```
probabilities=pred
print "probabilities", probabilities.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images},      session=sess)
```

At the end of the the day, the example below is what I was envisioning for an output for this network.  Assuming that I'm going down the wrong path, Could someone suggest the correct code to get output that would produce data similar to the example below with class and probabilities. Thank you.

```
[class] probability

[1] 0.0050
[2] 0.0124
[3] 0.8260
[4] 0.0001
 .
 .
 .
[113] 0.0008
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've come to a partial solution to this.

I added the line:

```
y_ = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(fc1,Wout) + Bout)
```

to the conv_net(...) function and then added the following line to the TestModels(...) function:

```
ProbOUT = probabilities.eval(feed_dict={x: fvecs_np}, session=sess)
```

Iterating through ProbOUT, gives me the following output:

```
0.0.....Cardiovirus A[51]
0.0.....Cardiovirus B[52]
0.0.....Foot-and-mouth disease virus[53]
0.0.....Equine rhinitis A virus[54]
0.0.....Bovine rhinitis B virus[55]
0.0.....Bovine rhinovirus 1[56]
0.0.....Teschovirus A[57]
0.0.....Ljungan virus[58]
1.0.....Human parechovirus[59]
0.0.....Aichivirus A[60]
0.0.....Kobuvirus sheep/TB3/HUN/2009[61]
0.0.....Mouse kobuvirus M-5/USA/2010[62]
```

This is great!, but why are the values 1 or 0?  I thought that by passing it though softmax I should be getting more precise probabilities.  This looks like it was passed through argmax.  Am I missing something?